# How can you change grid voltage in a vaccuum valve?

Tags: voltage, current, amplifier

I understand in a valve the level of amplification is determined by changes in the voltage of the grid or in the anode, but how can you change the voltage of the grid? And can this be done dynamically, so that you have different voltages over time?

Comment: Hey, please specify are you interested in how vacuum tubes generally work or how vacuum tube amplifiers work or do you want to know how one constructs a VCA ie. a vacuum tube amplifier which has a gain control voltage input? Your question as is can be considered a quite random writing done by a person who knows only some separate words in the field of electronics and electricity. One perfect answer would be "connect a battery between the grid and the cathode and change the battery to different when you feel it's time to change the voltage"

Comment: Thank you, so valve grids were connected to batteries that can be switched? Or that was an invention of yours?

Comment: Also, for AC I'm guessing you can switch with different transformers?

Comment: One transformer is enough, AC itself is the changing voltage as you obviously know.  But please, focus a little, otherwise you will get only bad jokes like the battery switching story (which technically is perfect) or nothing.

Comment: Alright, my question is sort of this: I know the basic functioning of a triode valve. What I was wondering was if the grid control voltage of a given tube could have changing or switching voltages, so as for a tube to produce changing current intensities, different amplifying powers in a single tube. So that you could change how much a single tube amplifies power by changing the voltage given to the control grid at will. And how would you achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input stages of tube radios and also of microphone amps handle so weak AC voltages (less than one millivolt) that altering the operating point of the amplifying tube can create large enough gain variation range without introducing too much distortion to the amplified AC signal.

[image]

In the left we have a generic triode amplifier. I have drawn a battery  "Gain control voltage" or shortly GCV. It actually gives the negative Vg. In radios that voltage comes from the signal detector. The bigger Vg is to negative direction, the smaller is the gain. That forces different AM radio stations to have the same output volume.

The gain reduction is based on the Ia vs Vg curve set at the right. You should see that Vg affects more steeply to the anode current Ia when Vg grows towards zero.

R1 is typically 1 MegOhm so the input AC isn't lost to GCV. C1 blocks DC but allows the AC signal to swing Vg around the GCV.

This is too simple for large signals, it can be used only at about 1mV or less input AC voltages.

Comment: So the different Vgs, I assume can be changed by switching between batteries, or changing resistances as in voltage dividers, right?

Comment: @AFedericoOsunaHdez true, but the gain control voltage can be outputted also by a more complex circuit - one that tries to keep the signal strength in certain limits by changing the gain when the signal strength varies.